# Itext 7 Loop using HtmlConverter.convertToElements but getting style from tags

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

I had these HTML strings:

```
<p><span style=\"color:#212529;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;font-size:1.0476190476190477rem;\">COR adah apl.</span></p>
```

However, when I convert them, the font-family does not change.
Here's my snippet:

```
List<IElement> elements = HtmlConverter.convertToElements(html);
```

I try using HtmlConverter.convertToPdf
but cant use it to loop my List of HTML String

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
The problem is 'Calibri' is not a default font-family in Itext7, so in order to use Calibri etc. You have to add it manually to the properties like below :

```
ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
            FontProvider fontProvider = new FontProvider();
            fontProvider.addFont(calibri);
            fontProvider.addFont(arial);
            fontProvider.addFont(segoe);
            properties.setFontProvider(fontProvider);
            List<IElement> elements = HtmlConverter.convertToElements(html, properties);
```